# Query data is deleted after exiting Firebase block

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I have a firebase query running to retrieve a user's stored search radius before passing the result to GeoFire.  It looks like this:

```
var searchRadius = Double()

ref.childByAppendingPath("/users/\(ref.authData.uid)/searchRadius").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

    self.searchRadius = snapshot.value as! Double
    print(self.searchRadius)
})
    print(self.searchRadius)
```

The first print line prints out my stored radius (in this case 4.xxxxxx), but it prints after the second print line outside the brackets.  So my result in my console ends up looking like:

```
0.0
4.xxxxxxxx
```

Why is this?  I encountered a similar problem with firebase and solved it with an ObserveReadyWithBlock, but this is my first time seeing the issue in Firebase.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The firebase query completes asynchronously, so your print statement that is after the block executes before the request is complete - this gives you the 0. When the query completes the completion closure executes, printing the 4.0

Comment: So when I'm passing to my GeoFire query, it's getting 0.0 because the data hasn't been served back to me yet.  How can I tell GeoFire to wait until the FireBase query is done serving?

Comment: The right approach is not to tell it to wait. Most of the the modern web is asynchronous and you're best of embracing it. Instead: reframe the operation from "first get A, then do B" to "when we get an A, do B with it".

Comment: As Frank says, you need to do the work in the closure, not outside

Comment: Thanks guys!  Much appreciated.